# p5 setVoice not working

Tags: p5.js

while trying to change the voices in the p5.speech, setVoice function just not working at all...
I've been tried both string and index, but still went wrong, is there anyone can help? I would be really appreciated!!
Thanks!

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.5/p5.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.5/addons/p5.dom.js"> 
  </script>
  <script src="p5.speech.js"></script>
  <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>   
 <button id='talks'>
  click to talk
 </button>
 <script>   
  $('#talks').click(function(){
  console.log('hi')
  var talk= new p5.Speech()
  talk.onLoad=Voices

  function Voices(){
  talk.listVoices()                    
  talk.setVoice('Google UK English Male') 
  }            
  talk.speak("What's up")}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the output of talk.listVoices() :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZZY1.jpg)

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman just did, wish it would help...thanks for your time :)

Comment: What output do you see when you call `talk.listVoices()`?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Hey I updated the output directly in the post! check it anytime if you got spare time :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly my answer is not the full solution, but there are some simple SyntaxErrors in your example. Thats why it's not runable for me at all.

1. You are opening **click(** but didn't close it, for better clearance i reformatted your code and added the closing bracket.
2. A function normally get's called with **brackets**, so it should be Voices();
3. This is not necessary for every Browser, but normally an ending line in JavaScript get's an ;

---

```js
$('#talks').click(
  function(){
    console.log('hi');
    var talk= new p5.Speech();
    talk.onLoad=Voices();

    function Voices(){
      talk.listVoices();                  
      talk.setVoice('Google UK English Male');
    }            
    talk.speak("What's up");
  }
)
```

---

With that changes i get an console output like this:

```
VM43:3: hi
p5.speech.js:136 p5.Speech: voices not loaded yet!
p5.speech.js:89 p5.Speech: voices loaded!
```

Comment: Hey yeah...that's the error,thanks for the correction!
but the problem still stays....lol

Comment: @游婷雅If you've changed your original code to fix these syntax problems, please update the code in your question so we're all running the same thing.